# How i can get ecommerce data from google api?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api-php-client

I use PHP Google Analytics library https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

But, now i need fetch data from Google Ecommerce.

Comment: I found 'Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_EcommerceData' class, but i do not know what do with it.

Comment: Please add your comment back into the question. Try to be more specific. Show what steps you have taken to get data from Google Ecommerce

Comment: I configured google client:
        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('app_name');
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->setAuthConfig('path/to/json/config');

But i don't know, how i can fetch ecommerce data, so i ask the question